# How can I evaluate $\int{\frac{x^3}{1+x^8}}\ dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

This question came up in a review assignment for my Calculus class, and I've been having difficulty solving it. I don't see what I could substitute for $u$, and it doesn't look like partial fractions are a viable method of doing this problem. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Evaluate the following indefinite integral: $$\int{\frac{x^3}{1+x^8}}dx$$

Answer (score 4):

Substitute $u=x^4$. The strategy is to get that numerator term $x^3$ to be someone's derivative. (Or a scalar multiple of it.)

Comment: Oh, I see. So we want $x^3$ to be a derivative so that we can use $u$-substitution.The original integral is the same as $\int(x^3)(\frac{1}{1+(x^4)^2})dx$, so we then set $u=x^4$. From there, $du=4x^3dx$ , so I can write the integral as $\frac{1}{4}\int\frac{1}{1+u^2}du$. This simplifies to $\frac14arctan(u)$, and if you plug in $x^4$ for $u$, you end up with the final answer as $\frac14arctan(x^4)$. Did I go wrong anywhere?

I'm still unsure that I'd be able to think of substituting like we did here on another problem.

Answer (score 1):

An obvious generalisation:
$$
\int\frac{x^{n-1}}{x^{2n}+1}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{n}\arctan{x^n}
$$
Proof:
$$
\int\frac{x^{n-1}}{x^{2n}+1}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{n}\int\frac{\mathrm{d}(x^n)}{(x^{n})^2+1}=\frac{1}{n}\arctan{x^n}
$$
You only need to notice that the derivative of $\displaystyle{\frac{x^n}{n}}$ w.r.t. $x$ is $x^{n-1}$, i.e. $\displaystyle{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\frac{x^n}{n}=x^{n-1}}$, and i.e.$\displaystyle{{\mathrm{d}}\left(\frac{x^n}{n}\right)=x^{n-1}\mathrm{d}x}$.

Answer (score 0):

This is an integral which requires trigonometric substitution. Since $\tan^2\theta+1=\sec^2\theta$, it is a good idea to substitue $x^4=\tan\theta$, then luckily we have $x^3dx=\frac14\sec^2\theta d\theta$. Hence
$$\int\frac{x^3dx}{x^8+1}=\int\frac{d\theta}{4}=\frac\theta 4+C=\frac14\arctan x^4+C$$